# How do I make Bootstrap popover work with HTML content in a seperate element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am in the process of combining Bootstrap panels with Bootstrap popover functionality. The goal is to show a popover when the user hovers the panel's header. I've already got this to work, except that the `data-content=""` part becomes quite unmanageable when it has a lot of HTML inside.

Below is some sample HTML I am working with. The part that says "LOADS OF HTML" contains div's, table's, p's, etc.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i> 
        <abbr title="Panel title" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" 
              data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" 
              data-content="<div>LOADS OF HTML HERE</div>">
          Panel title
        </abbr>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 pull-right" style="margin-top: -4px;">
            <!-- some buttons go here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
    </div>
    <!-- some panel content goes here -->
</div>
```

Other Bootstrap plugins solve this issue by allowing you to put the HTML in a separate element and then  reference that element with a "data-target" attribute. Unfortunately, Popover does not support this. How do I mimic this behavior without writing element specific JavaScript?

Comment: Why did you ask and answer the question?

Comment: Because StackOverflow promotes Q&A-style content? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Sweet info. Now I can finally post the questions I put loads of work into, only to find the answer myself, just before being ready to post it :). There has at least been a couple of times where it probably would have been relevant to others as well :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any text/HTML you want to display in the popover can be added in a `DIV` which has a `display:none;` CSS property to it.
You can pass a function to the `content` property of the popover options which gets the content from the hidden `DIV`.  This way one doesn't need to reference by ID and insert script tags.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/wb3n8/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title 1</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel content 1</div>
        <div class="my-popover-content">Here is some hidden content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title 2</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel content 2</div>
        <div class="my-popover-content">Here is some hidden content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title 3</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel content 3</div>
        <div class="my-popover-content">Here is some hidden content 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-popover-content {
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    popoverOptions = {
        content: function () {
            // Get the content from the hidden sibling.
            return $(this).siblings('.my-popover-content').html();
        },
        trigger: 'hover',
        animation: false,
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true
    };
    $('.panel-heading').popover(popoverOptions);
});
```

Comment: I like this solution as well so +1. No need to meddle with id's and you get to keep the popover content with the panel. The downsides are that it's designed specifically for panel's, makes assumptions about the whereabouts of the content and does not allow for reuse of popover contents.

Comment: This can be applied to any element in the DOM not just Bootstrap panels? Don't understand what you mean about assumptions of the whereabouts of the content?
As for reuse, this can be changed to work with the jQuery `hover` method which can then check for a pre-existing popover and just `show` or `hide` accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

An elegant solution is to place the HTML-content inside a script-tag with an id and then add a `data-target="element_id_goes_here"` attribute to the element that will trigger the popover. Since you're using popover you should already have some generic JavaScript somewhere that initializes the plugin. You can extend this JavaScript with a few lines of code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw"></i> 
        <abbr title="Panel title" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" 
              data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" 
              data-target="#my-popover-content">
          Panel title
        </abbr>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 pull-right" style="margin-top: -4px;">
            <!-- some buttons go here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
    </div>
    <!-- some panel content goes here -->
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="my-popover-content">
    *** HTML CONTENT GOES HERE ***
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").each(function(index, element) {
    var contentElementId = $(element).data().target;
    var contentHtml = $(contentElementId).html();
    $(element).popover({
        content: contentHtml
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution, based on Martin Devillers post, but more flexible (passes all data-* tags into bootstrap js)

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").each(function (index, element) {
    var data = $(element).data();
    if (data.target) {
        var contentElementId = data.target;
        var contentHtml = $(contentElementId).html();
        data.content = contentHtml;
    }
    $(element).popover(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

About Alexus1024 solution : I had to add a "#" before data.target in order to have jquery correctly selecting the target :

```
var contentElementId = "#"+data.target;
```