# Bootstrap 5 popover with HTML content as data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-popover

I want to show a Bootstrap 5 popover with custom HTML content. That means using the [`content`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/#options) option, and I can do that successfully the normal way (using javascript).

But I want to specify it in markup instead, as `data-bs-content`, without javascript. I tried this:

```html
<a role="button"
   tabindex="0"
   data-bs-html="true"
   data-bs-sanitize="false"
   data-bs-content="() => document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML"
   >Show popover</a>

<div id="foo" class="d-none">
  ...popover's content...
</div>
```

But the popover shows the literal text `() => document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML`.

Is my syntax incorrect, or is this impossible?

Comment: that's not HTML content FYI. That's string as you have wrapped within the quotes.

Comment: @OMiShah Yes. The issue is whether it's supported? I can do that in js, but haven't found a way to do it via a data attribute. Maybe it's not possible, though it would be a nice feature.

Comment: @Ionix, yes. BTW check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23538610/5882307 :)

Comment: @OMiShah Yeah that's another nice way to do it, placing the template in a script block rather than a normal dom element. It's still js :(, but it's neater :).